# pthread in cpp for different member functions in a class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

i started with a simple example
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm
i need to divide in the different cpps and headers i have as the following

class definition in Process_Images.h

```
void PrintHello(void* threadid);
```

in Process_Images.cpp

```
void ProcessImages::PrintHello(void* threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   std::cout << "Hello World! Thread ID, " << tid << std::endl;
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

in the main function

```
ProcessImages PI;

pthread_t threads[2];
pthread_create(&threads[0],NULL,PI.PrintHello,(void *)i);
```

the error is -->

```
/home/nvidia/Desktop/cms/tools/vibrante-vcm30t124-linux/cmsapplication_export/cmsapplication/sampleThread.cpp:333:69: error: cannot convert ���ProcessImages::PrintHello��� from type ���void (ProcessImages::)(void*)��� to type ���void* (*)(void*)���
      pthread_create(&threads[0],NULL,CarDetLEFT.PrintHello,(void *)i);
                                                                     ^
```

any suggestion please?

Comment: What's `i`? Try using `&i`

Comment: No, use C++11 threads instead of pthreads! Seriously, prepare a minimal example and you might find someone to solve this puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues :

- the thread function must return `void*`, not `void`
- the thread function cannot be a (non-static) member function

More details can be found on a reference page for [`pthread_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_create.html).

So, change the return type of `ProcessImages::PrintHello` to `void*` and make it `static` :

```
class ProcessImages {

  //<SNIP>

  public :
    static void* PrintHello(void* threadid);

  //<SNIP>

};
```

Then this should work better :

```
pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, &ProcessImages::PrintHello, (void*) i);
```

Comment: i have made it static, and change it void* when i compile i got a linking error undefifined reference to ProcessImages::PrintHello(void+)

Comment: @user3406305 : you need to also update the definition of `ProcessImages::PrintHello` accordingly (in Process_Images.cpp)

Answer (score 1):

Since I see C++11 tag in the question, there is absolultey no need to go over pthread route!

```
std::thread thr(&ProcessImages::PrinteHello, &PI, &i);
```

will do you good!